# how to make only the function sleep instead of the entire program in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

so like basically, sleep stops the entire script and this isnt good and I most likely dont want that, so any solutions to this? (it is for this boy right here):

```
    def on_button_click(self):
        global started
        if started==False:
            started=True
            enemyname = self.ids.starta.text
            self.type_text("")
            self.hide_widget(self.ids.starta)
            self.hide_widget(self.ids.startb)

            self.ids.thingy.opacity = 1
            self.ids.thingys.opacity = 1
            self.ids.thingyss.opacity = 1
            self.type_text("type this text")
            sleep(3)
            print("yes")
```

as you can see right here, I've tested stuff and the function right above the sleep gets delayed for 3 seconds but the print is printed instantly no idea how to explain it completely but this causes problems for sure as you can see, anyway I can fix this? (self.type_text uses Clock.schedule_interval and the function is from another question I've asked recently)

so yeah the main question is: how do I make it so that only this button function pauses instead of the whole thing

all related parts:

```
Builder.load_string("""

<BoxLayout>:
    orientation:"vertical"
    spacing:"10dp"
    TextInput:
        text: "type enemy name"
        size_hint:1,3
        id: starta
    Button:
        text:"Start"
        on_press: root.on_button_click()
        size_hint:1,3
        id: startb
    Label:
        id: label
        text: "Enter enemy name and press 'start'"
    Button:
        text:"Fight"
        size_hint: 1,.3
        color:1,0,0,1
        background_color:.5,0,0
        opacity:0
        id: thingy
    Button:
        text:"Guard"
        size_hint: 1,.3
        color:0,0,1,1
        background_color:0,0,.5
        opacity:0
        id: thingys
    Button:
        text:"Heal"
        size_hint: 1,.3
        color:0,1,0,1
        background_color:0,.5,0
        opacity:0
        id: thingyss
        
""")



class TextBox(BoxLayout):
    cache_text = StringProperty("") # For storing the entered text.
    index = NumericProperty(0) # For iteration over cache_text.
    global started
    def hide_widget(self, wid, dohide=True):
        if hasattr(wid, 'saved_attrs'):
            if not dohide:
                wid.height, wid.size_hint_y, wid.opacity, wid.disabled = wid.saved_attrs
                del wid.saved_attrs
        elif dohide:
            wid.saved_attrs = wid.height, wid.size_hint_y, wid.opacity, wid.disabled
            wid.height, wid.size_hint_y, wid.opacity, wid.disabled = 0, None, 0, True

    def type_text(self, txt, time=0.07):
        self.ids.label.text = ""  # Comment it out to retain the text.
        self.cache_text = txt # Store the entered text here.
        # For more control you may use method Clock.create_trigger.
        self.ev = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_text, time) # Update text after every 0.25 sec.

    def update_text(self, *args):
            if self.index < len(self.cache_text):
                val = self.cache_text[self.index]
                self.ids.label.text += val # Appending to existing text.
                self.index += 1
            else:
                self.index = 0 # Reset index.
                self.cache_text = "" # Clear cache.
                self.ev.cancel() # Cancel text updation.
    def on_button_click(self):
        global started
        if started==False:
            started=True
            enemyname = self.ids.starta.text
            self.type_text("")
            self.hide_widget(self.ids.starta)
            self.hide_widget(self.ids.startb)

            self.ids.thingy.opacity = 1
            self.ids.thingys.opacity = 1
            self.ids.thingyss.opacity = 1
            self.type_text("who you are fighting againist is %s, be careful. they are strong."% enemyname)


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return TextBox()

Test().run()
```

Comment: You should definitely check out (if you haven't already) [*how to ask*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question.

Comment: I believe I clarified things in short at the bottom post now @ApuCoder

Comment: From your updated post: do you want the function '*self.type_text("who you...*' to be called after few seconds while everything happens before it ?

Comment: yes, though I have solved the problem with a rather complicated way with the currently posted answer, thanks for trying to help though and ofc, really thanks for helping previously

Comment: Ok. However if that was the main problem, I think using `Clock.schedule_once` would have been sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are doing some kind of GUI.

The standard for GUI is to make a second thread to do the actual processing.

That is because if you process in the same thread the GUI is running, it actually remains frozen, as it can't handle the events from the user.

The processing thread must also send events to the GUI thread, to notify that the processing is completed.

So you want something like this:

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread


class ProcessingThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        sleep(20)
        print('ciao')
        
p=ProcessingThread()
p.start()
```

Note that you implement a `run` function, but you call `start`.

If you call `run` directly, it just runs like a normal function, but `start` is the method from the `Thread` class that actually creates the thread and then internally calls the `run` function.

Comment: I've got an error on this solution following:

     self.type_text("type THIS")
 TypeError: type_text() missing 1 required positional argument: 'txt' I will edit in the full thing

Comment: also sorry if the top thing made it confusing but yeah, the thing requires the "self" thing and I dont know how to refer "self" exactly so maybe you could try telling that and stuff ig I dont know what to exactly do to fix it

Comment: I believe I am onto something now